# Using IBM Tealeaf, require.js, and single page applications

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Can IBM Teamleaf be used on a single page application? Can it also be incorporated with require.js so that it is automatically included once and then picks up all javascript events that are fired?

I haven't used Tealeaf before, but our backend team does, and we're wondering if it is possible to combine it with a single page application that is mainly JS driven using require.js.

If so, should it be included on every single template page, just the main page, in our require.js file, or somewhere else?

Comment: If its not explictly amd can't you can always shim it, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tealeaf UIC creates a single global variable called `TLT` which you can easily shim. The API is designed to work with single page applications.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to some example source code that was easily shimmed?

Answer (score 0):

If the `TLT` object exists on the DOM where your application is loaded (however you got it loaded in there, like with require.js or some other method) you can then use any functionality from the library in your code. You'd probably want to do this where significant events on your front-end occur. Like if you had a React-Redux app with a `componentWillUnmount` firing at some significant UI action you wanted to track with Tealeaf, you could insert a `TLT.flushAll()` there to explicitly send a full snapshot to the collector at that instant. If HTML is being dynamically created and destroyed, fire `TLT.rebind()` after a create or destroy action to tell Tealeaf to re-observe the DOM to account for elements lost or created. I think the `TLT` API can be found here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/TLUIC/UICj2Guide/UIC/UICj2PublicAPIRef/UICaptureJ2PublicAPIReference.html

Comment: How can Tealeaf reliably capture the DOM in a React app since React uses virtual dom and the resulting DOM is not the same?